# Three different types of user for a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I'm looking to develop an application which will have three different types of users, upon login they will be either type 1, 2 or 3. I need user type 1 to be able to create accounts of type 2 and 3.

Is the best way to go about this using roles? And if so could anyone direct me to an article that would help me out, I'm currently having trouble trying to work out how to have a set amount of accounts and only let them login the system, then once they are logged in they can only access and modify the database in a way their type of account can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your app would be a good candidate to use the built in membership and roles providers. By using the built in providers you can save yourself reinventing the wheel. Check out the links from the following page:

[ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and Roles Tutorial Series](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

- Add a User Type Column in your user table.
- When each user logs in , store his user details in the session.
- Check the value of the UserType and show/hide the link to Edit/ Create
  user account.

If you want to do something broader and more flexble, you can create a Role table, a   Permission table and a table which stores Permissions for each role. You can associate a Role with a User.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built in Membership in ASP.net. It's already taken all of the security considerations, and works well out of the box. Here's a tutorial on Membership directly on the asp.net site.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

With .net's built in Membership you will be able to implement a very robust membership with built in support for users and roles (and a bunch of other stuff).

Comment: Thank you, what is this difference between roles and memberships?

Comment: Roles is a part of membership. At the basic level you have users, each user can belong to 1 or several roles.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to this is to use the ready made provider framework for ASP.Net

The role provider handles roles (obviously). You can make your own by deriving from RoleProvider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

or use the ready made one based on SQL Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx

The same goes for users (see [MembershipPriovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)

There are also Active Directory based ones for intranet applications.

Then you can restrict access to pages in your application based on the role they are in. For example, if you are using ASP.Net MVC you can use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) class
for some details.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, do you think ASP.NET MVC would be best suited for this type of application?

Comment: Well, you haven't specified very many details of your application, but I have found MVC to be a very clean and simple framework that leads to very maintainable code. Disclaimer: I've never done an ASP.Net web app without MVC though!